# How to use one component for validation other two components?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, validation

I have three components: `GalleryAddComponent` to add a new element, `GalleryItemComponent`, to edit an element, `FieldsComponent`, the form I want to use in the components: `GalleryAddComponent` and `GalleryItemComponent`. All components are inside the `GalleryComponent`. But when I go to the component `GalleryAddComponent` to add a new element I get the error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined`. Also in the component: `GalleryItemComponent`.

Help solve this problem so that the editing and adding logic works correctly.

**template of GalleryAddComponent**

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <form [formGroup]="angForm" novalidate>
                <app-fields [formGroup]="angForm"></app-fields>
            <div class="form-group but-group">
                <button (click)="addPost(title.value, url.value);  angForm.reset(title.value, url.value)"
                        [disabled]="angForm.pristine || angForm.invalid"
                        class="btn btn-primary">Add
                </button>
                <a routerLink="/" class="btn btn-danger">Back</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**code of GalleryAddComponent**

```js
export class GalleryAddComponent implements OnInit {
    angForm: FormGroup;
    isAdded: boolean = false;
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private galleryService: GalleryService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.angForm = this.fb.group({
            title: ['', Validators.required],
            url: ['', Validators.required]
        });
    }

    addPost(title: string, url: string): void {
        this.galleryService.add(title, url).subscribe(res => {
            this.isAdded = true;
        });
    }
}
```

**template of GalleryItemComponent**

```html
    <div class="card" *ngIf="toggleEdit">
        <h4>Edit your post</h4>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form [formGroup]="angForm" novalidate>
                <app-fields [formGroup]="angForm"></app-fields>
                <div class="form-group but-group">
                    <input type="button"
                           (click)="updatePost(title.value, url.value)"
                           [disabled]=" angForm.invalid"
                           class="btn btn-primary" value="Update Post">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**code of GalleryItemComponent**

```js
export class GalleryItemComponent implements OnInit {
   pic: Picture;
   angForm: FormGroup;
   
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private galleryService: GalleryService, private fb: FormBuilder) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.angForm = this.fb.group({
            title: ['', Validators.required],
            url: ['', Validators.required]
        });
        this.showPost();
    }

    showPost(): void {
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.galleryService.getPicture(params['id']).subscribe(res => {
                this.pic = res;
                this.angForm.setValue({title: res.title, url: res.url})
            })
        })
    }
    updatePost(title: string, url: string): void {
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.galleryService.update(title, url, params['id']).subscribe(res => {
                if (res.id === this.pic.id) {
                    this.pic.title = title;
                    this.pic.url = url;
                } 
            });
        });
    }
}
```

**template of FieldsComponent**

```html
<div [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4">Picture Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="title" minlength="1" #title/>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['title'].invalid && (angForm.controls['title'].dirty || angForm.controls['title'].touched)"
         class="alert alert-danger">
        <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['title'].errors.required">
            Title is required.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4">Picture Address (url)</label>
        <input type="url" class="form-control" formControlName="url" #url pattern="https?://.+"
               title="Include http://"/>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['url'].invalid && (angForm.controls['url'].dirty || angForm.controls['url'].touched)"
         class="alert alert-danger">
        Address(url) is required.
        <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['url'].errors.required ">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**code of FieldsComponent**

```js
export class FieldsComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() formGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

Comment: Could you please make a StackBlitz example out of your files? See https://stackblitz.com

Comment: @Roy https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cvf4ut
I am thinking of cutting the same input's with valodation from the "GalleryAddComponent" and "GalleryitemComponent" components and pasting them into a separate component. Then connect this component in the form in the component "GalleryAddComponent" and in the form of the component "GalleryitemComponent". But how to implement it without breaking the logic?

Comment: Could you please fix your stackblitz project to be able to run it?

Comment: @Balázs Takács https://stackblitz.com/github/gorillasz/gallery

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you are referencing `angForms.controls` in your `FieldsComponent` which only has one variable: `formGroup`.

Simply replace `angForms` in the template HTML code with `formGroup` and the issue should be resolved.

```
<div [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4">Picture Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="title" minlength="1" #title />
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="formGroup.controls['title'].invalid && (formGroup.controls['title'].dirty || formGroup.controls['title'].touched)"
    class="alert alert-danger">
    <div *ngIf="formGroup.controls['title'].errors.required">
      Title is required.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4">Picture Address (url)</label>
    <input type="url" class="form-control" formControlName="url" #url pattern="https?://.+" title="Include http://" />
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="formGroup.controls['url'].invalid && (formGroup.controls['url'].dirty || formGroup.controls['url'].touched)"
    class="alert alert-danger">
    Address(url) is required.
    <div *ngIf="formGroup.controls['url'].errors.required ">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did it, the error was the same, so I created my project in "StackBlitz" without a component "FieldsComponent" to show me how to put fields into a separate component and connect to the components: "GalleryAddComponent" and "GalleryitemComponent", without losing their logic

Comment: I have updated my answer slightly - please check if this works for you. (Also, neither of the StackBlitz links you provided actually showed the error you were getting, so I recreated this locally.)

Comment: [formGroup]="formGroup"  , this is not needed in div element

Answer (score 0):

I think the easy solution here, is to set up the formgroup in the parent component, and pass it on to the child components as input, hence it is given to the child component before the child component html is loaded.

The other solution I would recommend is to use the Resolve Technique offered by Angular, this allows you to load all data before a component is loaded with a quite straight-forward setup.

Here are some references:

- https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-router-resolve/
- https://alligator.io/angular/route-resolvers/

Answer (score 0):

Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined. This error can come only coz instead of **formGroup** you have used **angForm**. Try replacing it as shared by @Wrokar. Also what I understand is you want to show consolidated error messages. So instead of doing it in html for each formcontrol, you should do it in component.ts and make it more generic, by subscribing to value change of each control like below, and show the consolidated error message.

```
for (const field in this.formGroup.controls) { // 'field' is a string
  const control = this.form.get(field); // 'control' is a FormControl
  control.valueChanges.subscribe(
    (res) => {
       // check if it is pristine, dirty,  invalid, touched, pattern match if 
           any
       // you can access control.errors
       // create the consolidated list and append it in the list of error 
          messages
    }
  )
}
```

Its better to make it generic coz, tomorrow your form can have additional fields and then you dont have to change you FieldsComponent.